# when I install the application on the real gadget, 2 icons are created. Why?

Tags: android

My android project tree looks like that...  (I owner too "low reputation to post image", so...)

```
----------------------------
...
src 
   AppStart.java
   DBHelper.java
   SecureMessagesActivity.java
   Settings.java
   SmsReceiver.java
...
----------------------------
```

When I install app to real device, I can see two icons names 
1. SMS Cipher (project name)
2. Setting (click on this icon open settings.java)

It's unacceptably...
How can I avoid it? I just want that 1 icon was created.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably have the LAUNCHER/MAIN intent in 2 activities of your Manifest.xml, which tells the system you can start up your app from 2 entry points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems You have added  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` in two activities so this problem occurs.I would recommend you to add intent filter action main in only launcher activity which will the 1st activity of your App.

```
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
```

Don't use Action `MAIN` in more than one activity